# SQL Server: How to add multiple values from multiple counters

Tags: sql-server

I have different counters named Available Bytes, Committed Bytes, Modified Page List Bytes with different values. I want to add the values from these counters and all the values are under CounterValue.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Machine Name | Counter Name | Counter ID | CounterDateTime | Counter Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Machine 1    |Available Bytes | 1        | Dec 31st        | 123
Machine 1    |Committed Bytes | 2        | Dec 31st        | 223
Machine 1    |Modified Bytes  | 3        | Dec 31st        | 345
Machine 2    |Available Bytes | 4        | Dec 31st        | 467
Machine 2    |Committed Bytes | 5        | Dec 31st        | 567
Machine 2    |Modified Bytes  | 6        | Dec 31st        | 678
Machine 3    |Available Bytes | 7        | Dec 31st        | 467
Machine 3    |Committed Bytes | 8        | Dec 31st        | 567
Machine 3    |Modified Bytes  | 9        | Dec 31st        | 678
```

How do I go about doing this? 
[image: counter]

For instance, I want to do this:

1-[(Available Bytes)/(Available Byes + Committed Bytes + Modified Page List Bytes)] x 100 for each machine name

But I also want to keep the same table which contains the same columns.

Comment: Please _don't_ add external links to your question, unless it really contains critical information which can't be included directly in your question here.  This does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Sorry about that. That was a Fairly new here. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try conditional aggregation. Write a case, that only returns the value when the name is the one you want, 0 otherwise. Then sum it. Do this for all operands in your expression.

```
SELECT machine_name,
       counterdatetime,
       1
       -
       sum(CASE counter_name
             WHEN 'Available Bytes' THEN
               counter_value
             ELSE
               0
           END)
       /
       (sum(CASE counter_name
              WHEN 'Available Bytes' THEN
                counter_value
              ELSE
                0
            END)
        +
        sum(CASE counter_name
              WHEN 'Comitted Bytes' THEN
                counter_value
              ELSE
                0
            END)
        +
        sum(CASE counter_name
              WHEN 'Comitted Bytes' THEN
                counter_value
              ELSE
                0
            END)
        +
        sum(CASE counter_name
              WHEN 'Modified Bytes' THEN
                counter_value
              ELSE
                0
            END)) counter_value
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY machine_name,
                counterdatetime;
```

Comment: Thank you. That was I was looking for. But, I have multiple calculations to do. So one calculation is 1-[(Available Bytes)/(Available Byes + Committed Bytes + Modified Page List Bytes)] x 100 and the result is stored to a new column. However, I want to do another calculation unrelated to the first calculation so I created a sum(case) for this. I've tried doing this but it seems to be a stacked calculation, Is it possible to do multiple calculations returning result to different column?

Comment: For instance, the cases you did above, I did: sum(case (bunch of calculation) AS column 1 and then what I want to do is do another sum(bunch of calculation unrelated to the first calculation) AS column 2.

Comment: @123testing123: I don't really understand what you're asking but maybe sense a tendency... You can do whatever calculation that way, as long as there is a scalar expression in SQL Server for it and you use the `sum(CASE ... END)` as variables for it.

Comment: @123testing123: And of course you can use other expressions (or even the same) in that form for a second, third, ... _n_-th column. Just append like `, sum(...) <operator> sum(...) ... <column alias>` to the list after `FROM`.